# Biztalk flat file schema - how to use double quote as delimiter

Tags: schema, biztalk, flat-file

I have a flat file as

```
"barn","40","10,120","bill"
```

which I have to separate, I tried using quotes as delimiter but there is another quote and comma which creates another root child (",) which I don't need.

Comment: Can you show your current schema?

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the " as a wrap character, rather than a delimiter.  The delimiter should be a , and then you don't need another record.

[image: Field properties, wrap character]

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch2.Schema.SO77265759" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch2.Schema.SO77265759" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Root" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Record">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_order="infix" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="," />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" wrap_char_type="char" wrap_char="&quot;" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" wrap_char_type="char" wrap_char="&quot;" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" wrap_char_type="char" wrap_char="&quot;" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" wrap_char_type="char" wrap_char="&quot;" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Output

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch2.Schema.SO77265759">
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Field>barn</Field>
        <Field>40</Field>
        <Field>10,120</Field>
        <Field>bill</Field>
    </Record>
</Root>
```

Comment: How does when you add " in wrap it shows wrap_char="&quot;" in the schema, but when I add it it is wrap char="""

Comment: would this work only for one line, what do we do if there are mutiple rows or flat file data. thx

Comment: @John_Martin That is because it is escaping it as " is a reserved character in XML.  How are you adding it?  If you define the record as re-occurring it will work for all the lines.

Comment: I am adding the " to wrap though the properties as per your screenshot

Comment: @John_Martin  It might actually be "&quot;" in the file, but it is displaying it as """ in Visual Studio.  Try opening it with Notepad or Notepad++